# How to avoid having newlines with grep -o for multiple match at the same line?

Tags: grep

With `grep -o`, I have a new line for every match:

```
# echo "a b a"|grep -o a
  a
  a
```

How can I obtain the following result?

```
 # echo "a b a"|grep -o a
  a      a
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe the output of `grep` to `tr` that you can then use to translate `\n` (newline) to `\t` (tab):

```
echo "a b a" | grep -o a | tr "\n" "\t"; echo
```

where the last `echo` is used to prevent the output of `tr` from being on the same line as your `PS1`.

For the specific example you give, this is how it looks like:

```
$ echo "a b a" | grep -o a | tr "\n" "\t"; echo
a   a
```

Comment: This only works for the case of echoing a single string. This fails for the case of grepping through a file with multiple matches per line. Everything will be collapsed onto a single line.